# Bash/zsh function that cd to the root of git tree

Tags: bash, git

I'd like to get a review for the function that cd into the git tree root or does nothing if we are outside of the repository.

### reviewed version:

```bsh
# cd to the root of the current git directory
# If $PWD is submodule, will cd to the root of the top ancestor
# It requires to stay in the current directory, if the root is . or unknown,
# and use cd only once, to have a way to do `cd -`
function cg {
  git_root() {
    local super_root
    local top
    top="$(git rev-parse --show-cdup)"
    top="${top:-./}"
    super_root="$(git rev-parse --show-superproject-working-tree)"
    if [[ "$super_root" ]]; then
      printf '%s' "$top../"
      ( cd "$top../" && git_root || return )
    fi
    printf '%s' "$top"
  }
  local git_root
  git_root="$(git_root)"
  [ "x${git_root}" != "x./" ] && cd "$(git_root)" && return || return 0
}
```

### updated version:

```
#!/bin/bash
# cd to the root of the current git directory
# If $PWD is submodule, will cd to the root of the top ancestor
# It requires to stay in the current directory, if the root is . or unknown,
# and use cd only once, to have a way to do `cd -`
function cg {
  function git_root {
    local top; top="$(git rev-parse --show-cdup)"
    top="${top:-./}"
    local super_root; super_root="$(git rev-parse --show-superproject-working-tree)"
    if [[ "$super_root" ]]; then
      printf '%s' "$top../"
      ( cd "$top../" && git_root || return )
    fi
    printf '%s' "$top"
  }
  local tree_root
  tree_root="$(git_root)"
  [[ "x${tree_root}" != "x./" ]] && cd "${tree_root}" && return || return 0
}
```

Comment: just a suggestion, the single line `cd "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel || echo .)"` does the exact thing :) Taken from oh-my-zsh plugin: https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/blob/master/plugins/git/git.plugin.zsh#L238

Comment: Please do not edit the question after it has been answered. See [what should I not do](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @hjpotter92 no, sorry, it doesn't because it knows nothing about: a) symlinks; b) submodules. These two points forced me to invest time in the function above.

Comment: Thank you pacmaninbw, here's the updated version https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/252838/updated-bash-zsh-function-that-cd-to-the-root-of-git-tree

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Great

- 100% pass on [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) which means you're doing great with quoting everything that could be potentially problematic.
- scoping variables
- using `[[` conditional for the `if`
- nice explanation of what it is doing and why

## Could be better

- a sh-bang line at the top is a good idea for scripts, even if this would usually just be sourced during your login scripts.
- Your inner function is defined with different syntax than your outer function.
- You can scope and define a variable in one line.  For example: `local super_root="$(git rev-parse --show-superproject-working-tree)"`.  This makes sure you don't fail to define a local variable or fail to scope a new variable.  And it cuts out a line of code in each case.
- Reusing `git_root` for a variable name and the function name is confusing.  I initially wondered why you were trying to scope the function after you had just defined it.
- use `[[` conditional for conditional in the last line.

Comment: I know it's tagged [tag:bash], but I'd go the other way on your last comment, and turn the existing `[[` into a `[` test, so this function can more easily be adapted for other shells (I think that just leaves `local` as the only Bash feature used).

Comment: Thank you for your review!

Comment: 1) sure, makes sense; 2) true, I've missread the `name() ( code )` and `name() { code }` notations; 3) actually making one line `local top=...` cause complaints by shellcheck `SC2155: Declare and assign separately to avoid masking return values`. That's why I've decided to leave it this way; 4) yes, a little bit messy; 5) I see the point to make it POSIX-complaint, but this looks to me like a function for interactive shell, so I'll use `[[` in the latest line too.

Comment: Thanks for reviewing the review!  I like `[[` for safety, but I'm not worried about portability like Toby.  SC2155 applies because all your assignments involve subcommands, but you're already masking return values in a few places.

Comment: I like the cleaned up version, but to get a new review you're supposed to post a new question each time.