# Updated bash/zsh function that cd to the root of git tree

Tags: bash, git, zsh

here's the updated version of the [code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/252685/bash-zsh-function-that-cd-to-the-root-of-git-tree) for being reviewed. Fixes:

- "private" `_cg` function
- functions definition as `cg() {}`
- general clean-up

```
#!/bin/bash

# cd to the root of the current git directory
# If $PWD is submodule, will cd to the root of the top ancestor
# It requires to stay in the current directory, if the root is . or unknown,
# and use cd only once, to have a way to do `cd -`
cg() {
  _cg() {
    local top; top="$(git rev-parse --show-cdup)"
    top="${top:-./}"
    local super_root; super_root="$(git rev-parse --show-superproject-working-tree)"
    if [[ "$super_root" ]]; then
      printf '%s' "$top../"
      ( cd "$top../" && _cg || return )
    fi
    printf '%s' "$top"
  }
  local git_root
  git_root="$(_cg)"
  [[ "x${git_root}" != "x./" ]] && cd "${git_root}" && return || return 0
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is looking great.  Thanks for incorporating the previous improvements and coming back for another round of review.  I noticed a few new things this time:

- What does `printf '%s'` do for you that `echo -n` wouldn't?  Using `printf` when you're just passing through a string seems a little odd to me.  It should work either way, but `printf` would be more idiomatic for C where `echo` is much more common in shell scripts.
- Adding the `x` constants in the comparison `[[ "x${git_root}" != "x./" ]]` are not needed.  Using the double square brackets deals with the disappearing variables.  You would need the extra `x` for `[` comparisons because empty arguments become non-existant arguments which causes an error when you try to compare the non-existant to something.
- I would use `-n` in the `if [[ "$super_root" ]]; then` line like so: `if [[ -n "$super_root" ]]; then` to make clear what you're trying to do there.

Comment: I just found that didn't come back with "thank you". Thank you very much for your help! And the objectives behind the implementations: 1) I feel like `echo -n` is less portable than `printf`, that's why I stuck to it; 2) Thank you, I've learned something new; 3) perfectly makes sense too!